# When do I need Docker Volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Trying to make sure I understand the proper usage of docker volumes.  If I have a container running MongoDB that I plan to start and stop do I need a volume configured with I "docker run" the first time?  My understanding is that if use Docker run once, then docker stop/start my data is saved inside the container.  The volume is more useful if multiple containers want access to the data.  Is that accurate or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting and stopping a container will not delete the container specific data. However, you upgrade containers by replacing them with new containers. Any changes to the container specific read/write layer will be lost when that happens, and the new container will go back to it's initial state. If there are files inside your container that you want to preserve when the container is replaced, then you need to store those files in a volume, and then mount that same volume in the new container.